# Python For Loop to List

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a beginner Python question. I was wondering if it was possible to take the results of a for loop that came from a list and then turn it back into a list again. I've got code that looks something like this.

```
for a in mylist:
    result = q.myfunction(a)
    print q, a
```

I would like the results of this list to be something that I can use to create a table in my database. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7. I have looked through the documentation from python on for loops, and looked through questions on stack exchange, and I am still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

Just `print`ing things out obviously doesn't append them to a list. But calling the `append` method on a list does, as explained in the [Lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) section of the tutorial. For example:

```
mynewlist = []
for a in mylist:
    result = q.myfunction(a)
    print q, a
    mynewlist.append(result)
```

If *all* you want to do is create a new list, no other side effects, a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) makes it even simpler. This code:

```
mynewlist = [q.myfunction(a) for a in mylist]
```

… does the same as the above, but without the `print`.

Comment: Your for loop doesn't do the same thing as the list comprehension. The loop collects `(q,a)`, and the comprehension collects `(result, a)`.

Comment: @Dunes: Ah, good point. Obviously `(q, a)` isn't very useful, unless `q.myfunction` is only being called for side effects (in which case, why store the result in `result`?); edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to using for loops then you can do the following:

```
results = []
for a in mylist:
    result = q.myfunction(a)
    results.append(result)
```

However, the idiomatic way to do something like this in python is to use what's known as a list comprehension. List comprehensions are a way of producing new lists from the elements of others lists. For example, the following has exactly the same effect as the above for loop.

```
results = [q.myfunction(a) for a in mylist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
[q.myfunction(a) for a in mylist]
```

It's called a list comprehension.